# Word order in this sentence

Tags: word-order

I'm writing a poem. Does this sentence make sense?

> *"That song I have not yet of heard."*

In particular, is the word order correct?

Comment: No, in fact, it doesn't but this is like a right/wrong question. You need to show some explanation of your own or research....:)

Comment: It would ***have*** to be *...not yet **heard of***, rather than ***...of heard***. But such "non-standard word order" utterances are essentially ***literary***, and not really relevant to the needs of people learning English. If you want help writing ***poetry***, you should probably post on [SO writers,](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) not here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think the question is all right here. It's related to grammar more than poetry.

Comment: poetry: **That song I have not heard of yet**. And this is something I might bet. You make your bed and sleep outside, so who am I to say you lie?

Answer (score 1):

There is the phrasal verb "hear of"  and the words do have to be in that order (but see later) so you would need to say

> That song I have not yet heard of

However "hearing of a song" is not the same as "hearing a song". So perhaps you mean

> That song I have not yet heard.

Since the last part could be relative clause, you can phrase it using the formal:

> That song of which I have not yet heard

Or it might be intended as "yodaised" version of

> I have not yet heard [of] that song.

Of course, these might not fit the rhyme or meter of your poem.  That I can't really help with.